# operations on turing machine

Tags: time-complexity, turing-machines

Consider the problem: List := {< A, c> | A is a list of integers that contains a,b such that a + b = c} where the length of A is n.
The algorithm we use to show that this problem is in class P adds two integers say A[i]+A[j] from A and check if it is equal to c or not. why can this test can be done in O(1)rounds?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So the input is a list of `n` numbers, and one additional number called `c`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes and I just rephrased my question, please and thank you.

Comment: The test is `A[i] + A[j] == c`. That test takes the same amount of time, regardless of how many entries there are in the array. So we say that the test is O(1), and we perform that test O(n^2) times.

Comment: We cannot. Comparison is not O(1). Addition is not O(1). Incrementing a counter is not O(1). Numbers have size, and the time of all these operations is proportional to that size. If we are talking about the Turing machine, that is.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches when speaking of computational complexity:

- The involved integers are considered to be single words, i.e. they have a fixed range that typically fits in one CPU register. This could for instance be a signed 64-bit integer.
- The involved integers are considered to be unbounded: the memory to hold them will vary. Unless algorithms really work with so-called "big integers", this is a more theoretical approach.

We see the first approach in Wikipedia's article on [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). For instance, for [linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time) it gives this example:

> For example, a procedure that adds up all elements of a list requires time proportional to the length of the list, if the adding time is constant, or, at least, bounded by a constant.

The second approach is taken in Wikipedia's article on [computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations). For instance, for [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions) it has:

> | Operation | Input | Output | Algorithm | Complexity |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Addition | Two -digit numbers, and | One +1-digit number | Schoolbook addition with carry | Θ(), Θ(log()) |

### For the algorithm in question

I'll assume that the list members are signed integers.

Both the addition and comparison of two integers has O(1) time complexity according to the first approach, and so the overall time complexity is O(²).

According to the second approach both addition and comparison are O(log(max(abs())). We could also involve  here: but even if it has a greater absolute value than all the sums of pairs, we can do the comparison with a time complexity of max(abs())). And so the overall time complexity is O(log(max(abs()))²).

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot!  Just to finally check something, would this then imply that, using the first approach, we can count how many elements in a list in time proportional to the length of the list?

Comment: If you want to count the elements *whose sum is c*, then you can do it in a time complexity of O(n). This assumes you have access to a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) that can store & find a unique value with an **average** time complexity of O(1). If the values in the list have a small range (like 1...n), then you can use an auxiliary array instead of a hash table, and then you always have O(1) lookup time.

Comment: So if A is a list of numbers  (that have small range) whose length is n, we can count how many elements in O(n) time?

Comment: If with "count" you mean "count the pairs whose sum is c": yes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, my question now is different, take an example A= <1,2,10> I want to count how many elements in A which is 3 in this case that would take linear in length of A?

Comment: Yes, that's linear

Comment: Thank you a lot